# Setting up MongoDB 3.4 on RaspberryPi3

Tags: database, mongodb, performance, raspberry-pi3

I would like to run `MongoDB 3.4` on `RaspberryPi3`  but I don't know if it makes sense for my problem.

Do You have any experience connected with working with this stack? Could You tell me about this? Which `64bit OS` do You use? How much data do You store? Can I ask how often do You insert data into `DB`? I'm asking because in my project the database will be heavily updated? Do You have any problem with performance? I will be grateful for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install mongodb-org=3.4.1 mongodb-org-server=3.4.1 mongodb-org-shell=3.4.1 mongodb-org-mongos=3.4.1 mongodb-org-tools=3.4.10
```

Here is the guide http://www.techoism.com/install-mongodb-3-4-ubuntu-16-0414-04/